# How can I access $(this) using a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, selector, this

I'm using jQuery rating [plugin](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jrating) and I am having trouble displaying success message into corresponding div because $(this) does not refer to selector but returns Object object instead.

[Here's plugin code](https://github.com/alpixel/jRating/blob/master/jquery/jRating.jquery.js)

Here's my code :

```
  $(".basic").jRating({
     bigStarsPath: 'assets/stars.png',
     rateMax: 5,
     length : 5,
     phpPath : '<%= Rails.application.class.routes.url_helpers.ratings_path %>',
     onSuccess : function(){
       $(this).find(".message").append('<small>Thanks for your vote!</small>'); 
     }
   });
```

So the problem is that $(this) does not refer to $(".basic") and I wonder how can I access selector within the plugin.
I'm pretty sure this may be newb question but my javascript skills are not extensive at all.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Object object` is what you get when you convert an object to string. Trying to debug with `alert($(this))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to jRating source code [code line](https://github.com/alpixel/jRating/blob/master/jquery/jRating.jquery.js#L175) the arguments which will pass to onSuccess and onError handlers are element and rating so the solution would be:

```
$(".basic").jRating({
 bigStarsPath: 'assets/stars.png',
 rateMax: 5,
 length : 5,
 phpPath : '<%= Rails.application.class.routes.url_helpers.ratings_path %>',
 onSuccess : function(element /*, rating */){
   $(element).find(".message").append('<small>Thanks for your vote!</small>'); 
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `onSuccess` is `element`. Use that.

```
onSuccess : function(element){
  $(element).find(".message").append('<small>Thanks for your vote!</small>'); 
}
```

It is up to the plugin to set `this` to something, and in this case the plugin triggers the `onSuccess` function with `this` as the `options` object you have passed to `jRating` rather than the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
 onSuccess : function(element, rate){
   $(element).find(".message").append('<small>Thanks for your vote!</small>'); 
 }
```

You can access element and / or rate in the Success option.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var elem = $(this);
$(".basic").jRating({
     bigStarsPath: 'assets/stars.png',
     rateMax: 5,
     length : 5,
     phpPath : '<%= Rails.application.class.routes.url_helpers.ratings_path %>',
     onSuccess : function(){
       elem.find(".message").append('<small>Thanks for your vote!</small>'); 
     }
   });
```